# Flutter TabBarView build all tab widgets once at startup

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently trying to get a multi tabbed form working. I am using the package `flutter_form_builder` for that.

The problem is, that the FormBuilder requires all descendant form fields to be loaded at least once to run validations and to provide the correct value of the field. When the user visits every tab once the thing works fine, but I cannot assume that this will always happen.

The simplest solution in my eyes would be, to somehow get the TabBarView to render all tab pages at startup, so that every tab-widget and the form-fields exist.

I have the main page where I define the form builder and the tabview inside of it. The important part looks like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: 'title',
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: tabController,
          tabs: <Widget>[
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.title)),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.image)),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.category)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: FormBuilder(
          key: formBuilderKey,
          autovalidate: true,
          child: TabBarView(
            controller: tabController,
            children: <Widget>[
              MainTab(),
              CoverTab(),
              GroupsTab()
            ],
          )
        )
    );
}
```

One tab page looks more or less like this:

```
class GroupsTab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return GroupsTabState();
  }
}

class GroupsTabState extends State<GroupsTab> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
            FormBuilderTextField(
                attribute: "name",
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Name",
                  icon: Icon(Icons.title),
                ),
                validators: [FormBuilderValidators.required()],
            ),
            // Page content with form fields
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

I'm already using the `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` to only call the build method of every tab page once but I need a bit more.

So my question: Is it possible to get the TabBarView to render all the widgets at startup or do you have an idea for a different solution.

Thank you all guys in advance

Comment: Did you find any solution? I too want to build all tabs at once. In native Android, it's acheived very easily by setting `offscreenPageLimit`.

Comment: Sadly no. Had to change the layout to something less awesome.

Comment: @MorrisJanatzek What did you end up having to do? Running into this exact issue

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: I found this question because I had the same problem. I solved this by using an `IndexedStack` instead of 'TabBarView` because in this case the FormBuilder fields are created regardless on which stack they are. I used a custom navigation bar to switch between stacks.

Comment: You can try reactive_forms (https://pub.dev/packages/reactive_forms) to manage forms. It solve all my headache with complex form

Answer (score 0):

if it can help anyone

```
int currentTabIndex = 0;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return DefaultTabController(
  length: 2,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      toolbarHeight: 0,
      bottom: TabBar(
        tabs: [
          Tab(_buildWidget1),
          Tab(_buildWidget2),
        ],
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            currentTabIndex = index;
          });
        },
      ),
    ),
    body: TabBarView(
      children: [
        if (currentTabIndex == 0) _buildWidget1() else Container(),
        if (currentTabIndex == 1) _buildWidget2() else Container(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Important:  this thing is working, but kindly consider this as a workaround. And cannot be a reliable permanent solution. It'll initialize all the classes in one go. I am showing the loader in the foreground while functioning the tasks in the background until and unless the process of initializing ends.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) async {
      isLoading = true;
      setState(() {});

      await functionInitAll();

      isLoading = false;
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> functionInitAll() async {
    _tabController.animateTo(0);
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));

    _tabController.animateTo(1);
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));

    _tabController.animateTo(2);
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));

    _tabController.animateTo(0);
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));

    return Future<void>.value();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        afterInit(),
        whileInit(),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget whileInit() {
    return Visibility(
      visible: isLoading,
      child: const Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget afterInit() {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          tabs: const <Widget>[
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.one_k)),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.two_k)),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.three_k)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: const <Widget>[
            ClassA(),
            ClassB(),
            ClassC(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ClassA extends StatefulWidget {
  const ClassA({super.key});

  @override
  State<ClassA> createState() => _ClassAState();
}

class _ClassAState extends State<ClassA> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("Init A");
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print("Dispose A");
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}

class ClassB extends StatefulWidget {
  const ClassB({super.key});

  @override
  State<ClassB> createState() => _ClassBState();
}

class _ClassBState extends State<ClassB> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("Init B");
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print("Dispose B");
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}

class ClassC extends StatefulWidget {
  const ClassC({super.key});

  @override
  State<ClassC> createState() => _ClassCState();
}

class _ClassCState extends State<ClassC> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("Init C");
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print("Dispose C");
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your current implementation, the `TabBarView` in Flutter's `TabBar` widget only renders the currently visible tab and the adjacent tabs. This is done for performance reasons, as it avoids building all the tabs upfront, especially if they contain heavy or complex widgets.

However, if you want to ensure that all the tabs in the `TabBarView` are built and their form fields are initialized, you can leverage the `IndexedStack` widget along with the `TabBar` and `TabBarView`. Here's how you can modify your code:

1. Replace the `TabBarView` with an `IndexedStack`:

```dart
IndexedStack(
  index: tabController.index,
  children: <Widget>[
    MainTab(),
    CoverTab(),
    GroupsTab(),
  ],
)
```

2. Update the `build` method of your `GroupsTab` to include a `Visibility` widget:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  super.build(context);
  return Visibility(
    visible: widget.visible,
    maintainState: true,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          FormBuilderTextField(
            attribute: "name",
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Name",
              icon: Icon(Icons.title),
            ),
            validators: [FormBuilderValidators.required()],
          ),
          // Other form fields
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}

@override
bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
```

3. In your main page, define the visibility property for each tab:

```dart
bool mainTabVisible = true;
bool coverTabVisible = false;
bool groupsTabVisible = false;

// Inside the build method
IndexedStack(
  index: tabController.index,
  children: <Widget>[
    MainTab(visible: mainTabVisible),
    CoverTab(visible: coverTabVisible),
    GroupsTab(visible: groupsTabVisible),
  ],
)
```

By using the `IndexedStack`, all the tab pages will be built at startup, but only the currently visible tab will be shown. The `Visibility` widget ensures that the form fields in the invisible tabs are not validated or updated until they become visible.

You can update the visibility properties (`mainTabVisible`, `coverTabVisible`, `groupsTabVisible`) based on user interactions or any other logic in your application to control which tabs are initially visible.

With this approach, you can ensure that the form fields in all the tabs are initialized and ready for validation, even if the user doesn't visit all the tabs initially.